# Cannot read from Excel sheet when worksheet name has spaces

Tags: c#, excel

I want to take data into a `combobox` from an excel sheet. But, the sheetname is not like `sheet1$`. My excel sheet name is `Sac Haddehanesi Kalite Kontrol`. When I made my sheet name `sheet1`, it works. But, the excel file is sent everyone and it is sheet name given by another guy. So, I have to use the original sheet name and cannot read it by the code below:

```
pintu(textBox8.Text);
try
{
    con.Open();
    str = "SELECT * FROM  [Sac Haddehanesi Kalite Kontrol$]";
    com = new OleDbCommand(str, con);
    oledbda = new OleDbDataAdapter(com);
    ds = new DataSet();
    oledbda.Fill(ds, "Sac Haddehanesi Kalite Kontrol$");
    con.Close();
    dt = ds.Tables["Sac Haddehanesi Kalite Kontrol$"]; 
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i <= dt.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
        comboBox1.DataSource = dt;
    comboBox1.DisplayMember = "[Bobin ID]";
```

Here's an image of my spreadsheet:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After debugging the issue myself, seems there's a problem with reading the sheet name when it has special characters.

Try reading from the sheet according to its **index** rather than its name.

The following code reads all sheet names into a temporary `DataTable`, gets the 1st sheet name and uses it in the rest of the code:

```
con.Open();

// Read all sheet names into a temporary data table
DataTable dtExcelSheetName = con.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);

// Get the FIRST sheet name
string sheetName = dtExcelSheetName.Rows[0]["Table_Name"].ToString();

// Now use this name to select
str = "SELECT * FROM  [" + sheetName +"]";

com = new OleDbCommand(str, con);
oledbda = new OleDbDataAdapter(com);
ds = new DataSet();
oledbda.Fill(ds, sheetName);
con.Close();
dt = ds.Tables[sheetName];
```

Answer (score 0):

I found when I was doing VBA for Excel Macro, every sheet actually has 2 names. Name (Name). There is a name for the title (that you showed) when you open with Excel, but also another name to reference in VBA or other code.

See below in the Excel Sheet **Properties**:

In Excel, the sheet title is "Can Have Space". This is what you see in the tab for the sheet when you open an Excel file.

In code, the sheet alias/title is actually "CannotHaveSpace". This is what you use to reference this sheet in any code instance. This name cannot contain spaces.

[image: Spaces]

I hope these helped someone out there with the same issues! :)